# How can I set the address attribute of a System.ServiceModel.Client.Endpoint object in code?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

First off, I'm not a web developer, so go easy on me..

I inherited a project which utilizes a web services client.  I'm looking to be able to deploy the same .config file across multiple environments without having to edit it directly.  To that end, the only attribute that I'm not sure how to deal with is the address in the `<system.serviceModel>` section:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CA_ServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="1000000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="16384" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="CA_ServiceSoap1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://myserver.contoso.com/CA_Service.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CA_ServiceSoap" contract="WebServices.CA_ServiceSoap" name="CA_ServiceSoap"/>
</client>
```

Is there a way I could enter a dummy value for the "address" attribute in the `<endpoint>` tag in .config, and then properly define it at runtime via code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @S.Dav for pointing me in the right direction on this.  What I ended up doing is including everything in the XML that I posted (which itself is just a serialized object) directly in my code.  The only attribute that is variable is the URL:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
{
    Namespace = "WebServices.CA_ServiceSoap",
    CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
    OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,1,0),
    ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,10,0),
    SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,1,0),
    AllowCookies = false,
    BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
    HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard,
    MaxBufferSize = 1000000,
    MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000,
    MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text,
    TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
    UseDefaultWebProxy = true,
    ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
    {
        MaxDepth = 32,
        MaxStringContentLength = 16384,
        MaxArrayLength = 16384,
        MaxBytesPerRead = 4096,
        MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384
    }
};
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity()
{
    ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None,
    ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None,
    Realm = ""
};
binding.Security.Message = new BasicHttpMessageSecurity()
{
    ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName,
    AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default
};
client = new CA_ServiceSoapClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(Config.WebServiceURL));
```

As a future to-do, I plan to see if any of these binding attributes might need to be adjusted for troubleshooting/performance & add them as appsettings which I will then reference in the BasicHttpBinding instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to to change the address of an endpoint with `basicHttpBinding` in code when creating the client.

Based on the config you provided I guess your code to create a client could be similar to the following:

```
//Specify the binding to be used for the client.
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding() { Namespace = "WebServices.CA_ServiceSoap" };

//Specify the address to be used for the client.
EndpointAddress address =
     new EndpointAddress("https://myserver.contoso.com/CA_Service.asmx");

// Create a client that is configured with this address and binding.
CA_ServiceSoap client = new CA_ServiceSoap(binding, address);
```